# Mongo: How to enable strict FIFO data retrieval?

Tags: mongodb, fifo

I have a mongo collection I'd like to retrieve in first in, first out (FIFO) order. We're batch-importing a few hundred tasks each sec and from what I understand, documents imported within the same second are not necessarily retrieved in the same order they were inserted.

To quote from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/:

> The relationship between the order of ObjectId values and
>   generation time is not strict within a single second. If multiple
>   systems, or multiple processes or threads on a single system generate
>   values, within a single second; ObjectId values do not represent a
>   strict insertion order. Clock skew between clients can also result in
>   non-strict ordering even for values, because client drivers generate
>   ObjectId values, not the mongod process.

My question is: is there a common practice for ensuring strict FIFO in mongo? At the moment we're tempted to add a new key w/nanoseconds, but adding an entire column just to ensure FIFO seems a little excessive. Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: I think you're on the right track with the index idea.

Comment: Do you need all of the documents to live in the collection for an indeterminate amount of time?  If not look at capped collections and tailable cursors. I did a talk on turning MongoDB into a queue broker at MongDB DC: http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/mongo-db-tricks-mongodc-march-11-2013-v2

Comment: As Rob suggested, you can look for capped collection to get the insertion order but it has a limit on collection size. Or you may look for `$natural` sort ordering. Note: This sort ordering will be different from the insertion ordering, if there are document moves because of updates.

Comment: Another option is to use a zero'd MongoDB Timestamp as the first field of the inserted document.  It will then be filled (at the server) with a monotonically increasing value: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#timestamps I have never used this feature so...